# GZip on Linux to archive files specified in the text file

Tags: linux, list, file, gzip, archive

I have a text file with paths to the list of files I want to compress into a singe archive. How can I pass this file to GZIP so it can create that archive with all files specified in the list?

Milan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gzip can only handle a single file at a time. You'll need to archive the files using tar first. Tar can do the compression at the same time (using the "z" argument).

```
tar cfz archive.tar.gz `cat file`
```

Comment: x extracts, you need to use c.

Comment: What does filelist look like?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the first place, `gzip` doesn't compress multiple files into a single one, so you'll first `tar`. At least the GNU `tar` I checked has the option

> ```
>   -T, --files-from F
>           get names to extract or create from file F
> ```

so I suppose `tar cfzvT target.tar.gz sourcelist` would work.

Comment: I always love the concatenation of options when using tar.

Comment: @Gorilla: Windows has earned a notoriety in that respect, where a common combination was `xcopy /k/r/e/i/s/c/h`, "kreischen" being German for (hysterical) screaming. I don't know what the switches do, but I'll never forget the combination.

Answer (score 0):

gzip only compresses a single file. Use:

```
tar czf target.tar.gz `cat listoffile`
```