# shell command for rename followed by gzip on multiple files with matching pattern

Tags: shell

I have many files with extension .txt in a folder. I would like to
first rename them and then zip all these files using gzip. Is there a way to read in all the .txt files and execute mv followed gzip as a loop, instead of doing

```
mv file1.txt file1_n.txt
gzip file1_n.txt
mv file2.txt file2_n.txt
gzip file2_n.txt
```

....which is very cumbersome. I know that I can grep for the pattern .txt in the filenames but not sure how to store each one as a variable and loop for mv followed by gzip.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040669/gzip-on-linux-to-archive-files-specified-in-the-text-file

Comment: `tar -czf txt.tgz *.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your shell is bash, use a for loop:

```
for FILE in $(ls file*.txt); do
    NEWFILE="${FILE%.*}"_n.txt
    mv "$FILE" "$NEWFILE"
    gzip "$NEWFILE"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
 find -name "*.txt" -exec rename -e 's/.txt/_n.txt/' {} \;  ; gzip *_n.txt
```

Explanation:

- `find -name "*.txt"` searches for files ending in `*.txt`
- `-exec rename -e 's/.txt/_n.txt/' {} \;` renames the files
- `; gzip *_n.txt` gzips all files ending in `_n.txt`

So as example with your file:

```
$touch file1.txt file2.txt
$ ls
file1.txt  file2.txt
$ find -name "*.txt" -exec rename -e 's/.txt/_n.txt/' {} \;  ; gzip *_n.txt
$ ls
file1_n.txt.gz  file2_n.txt.gz
```